# asp.net mvc web application error "cannot attach database ... as ... "

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am developing an ASP.NET web application named Spotlight but keep getting this error. I have Visual Studio 2013 and I can't seem to find the database at all in the Server Explorer. I also checked the App_Data folder and it is completely empty. Would someone help me on this?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\*MYNAME*\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Spotlight\Spotlight\App_Data\Spotlight.Models.SpotlightDb.mdf' as database 'Spotlight.Models.SpotlightDb'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\*MYNAME*\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Spotlight\Spotlight\App_Data\Spotlight.Models.SpotlightDb.mdf' as database 'Spotlight.Models.SpotlightDb'.

Source Error: 



Line 14:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 15:         {
Line 16:             var model = _db.Companies.ToList();
Line 17: 
Line 18:             return View(model);


 Source File:  c:\Users\*MYNAME*\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Spotlight\Spotlight\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line:  16 

Stack Trace: 



[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\*MYNAME*\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Spotlight\Spotlight\App_Data\Spotlight.Models.SpotlightDb.mdf' as database 'Spotlight.Models.SpotlightDb'.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +414
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +34
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +196
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +516

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +629
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +173
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +86
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9() +270
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +598
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +89
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +416
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +40
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +83
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +107
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +197
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +149
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +251
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.EdmMetadataRepository.QueryForModelHash(Func`2 createContext) +375
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModelHash() +179
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +184
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +99
   System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata) +43
   System.Data.Entity.<>c__DisplayClass1.<InitializeDatabase>b__0() +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.MigrationsChecker.IsMigrationsConfigured(InternalContext internalContext, Func`1 databaseExists) +116
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +349
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClasse`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__d() +165
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +110

[DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +166
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +626
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +31
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +143
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +292
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +42
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +138
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +38
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +108
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   Spotlight.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\*MYNAME*\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Spotlight\Spotlight\Controllers\HomeController.cs:16
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690164
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

Comment: Did that database already exist?

Comment: Did database available? if yes then first you have to attach database.

Comment: visual studio used to do all those for me but last week it stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears your database does not exist, you would first need to create it in the App_Data Folder.

Comment: I thought visual studio was gonna create it for me. It worked before.